MP_RETURN_IF_ERROR(m_Graph.Initialize(config)))
I'm debugging with the dll of my self-compiled mediapipe face_mesh, but I'm getting an error at this location(
std::string calculator_graph_config_contents;
MP_RETURN_IF_ERROR(mediapipe::file::GetContents(model_path, &calculator_graph_config_contents));
std::cout << "mediapipe::file::GetContents success" << std::endl;

mediapipe::CalculatorGraphConfig config =
    mediapipe::ParseTextProtoOrDie<mediapipe::CalculatorGraphConfig>(
        calculator_graph_config_contents); 
MP_RETURN_IF_ERROR(m_Graph.Initialize(config))) : 

Exception raised: Read access conflict.
the config is null.  but calculator_graph_config_contents not null.
I don't know  what the problem is and how to proceed anymore

Is mediapipe::CalculatorGraphConfig config not null? Maybe add a log statement to verify this or use a debugger?

@kiner_shah mediapipe::CalculatorGraphConfig config is null, but std::string calculator_graph_config_contents is not null , i have tried

That probably means, mediapipe::ParseTextProtoOrDie is failing to parse your string calculator_graph_config_contents to object mediapipe::CalculatorGraphConfig. Check if your string is correct and whether parsing to the object is possible with that string.
